# How to have Common button in 2 different activities?

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I have a Button which I want to show in 2 different activities. The button action does same thing for both activities like toggling on/off feature.

Is there any good way to get same button in both activities without copying and pasting code in both activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate the action to perform into a third object

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Delegate delegate = new Delegate();

    public void onCreate(...) {
        ....
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> delegate.doSomething());
    }
}

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Delegate delegate = new Delegate();

    public void onCreate(...) {
        ....
        otherButton.setOnClickListener(v -> delegate.doSomething());
    }
}

public class Delegate {

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }

}
```